# What are the pilot rating requirements for amphibians?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, amphibian

I know that both land and sea planes require pilot ratings in order to act as pilot-in-command.

What is the requirement to act as pilot-in-command of an [amphibian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibious_aircraft)?

Is there a third rating or just seaplane and land ratings?

What about flights taking off and landing exclusively on either water or land but not both?

Comment: I can't quote the regs (or I would answer instead of comment) but my understanding is you can fly it as long as your flight (landing) is consistent with your certificate. I know someone who owns an amphibian (http://www.lakeamphib.com/lakeamphib.htm) and only has an ASEL, currently working on his ASES, and while it's possible he's flying it illegally, neither his CFI nor the Lake factory have raised an issue with him and both are aware of the situation.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, frogs are not allowed to fly planes.  Newts, I'm less sure about. \*rimshot\*

Comment: Just to update your terminology:  A pilot has a Pilot Certificate, not a license.  Right now it contains an endorsement for ASEL.  After seaplane training the same Certificate will contain an additional endorsement: ASES.  So no need for a separate "license", just multiple endorsements on his certificate.  And if he is only using the Lake Amphib to land on runways, he is legal (I think.  Not sure of this last statement).

Comment: @SkipMiller: my bad, where I used to live (Australia) it was indeed called a "licence", just forgot about that distinction. Thanks!

Comment: Actially @SkipMiller, those are ratings

Comment: Thank you @rbp this questions nomenclature is completely wrong.  Sea operations do not get granted by endorsements in the FAA system.  Those would be ratings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Seaplane Pilots Association](http://www.seaplanepilotsassociation.org/resources/faq/airman-issues/) you can operate an amphibious airplane on hard-surface runways with a land class rating but need a seaplane class rating to take off or land on water, and vice versa.

As far as the regs, it seems that the airplane can simply be considered either land or seaplane class depending on how you are operating it.

Comment: any regulations about taking off?

Comment: I was gonna answer, but this is correct, so no need!

Comment: @ratchetfreak I would assume you need the appropriate rating (Land or Sea) for either takeoff or landings. (Or two pilots - one qualified for Land and the other for Sea...)

Comment: so to move a plane from hard to water (or vice versa) you need both types of ratings in the cockpit, (either in one pilot or in 2)?

Comment: @ratchetfreak that's a good question. It's pretty common for seaplanes with straight floats to switch to wheels during the winter, and the process involves landing on grass with the floats so the shop can remove them. To reverse it, the shop puts the floats back on and the airplane takes off from land using a wheeled dolly. So... is a land plane rating required in that case? :)

Comment: @egid What, [no video?](http://youtu.be/Temm5lI-zUI?t=2m36s) :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 Wow! Do you need an ASET (airplane - single engine - truck) rating for that? Awesome... never seen that.

Comment: @egid Wouldn't it be better to land the floatplane near a boat dock and haul it out on dollies?

Comment: @DJClayworth that only works if there is a runway next to the seaplane base. Like, *right* next to. The procedure is used when swapping out floats for wheels - so in some locations, like Renton, WA (KRNT) what you suggest is the best option. In others, you do what you can.

Comment: @voretaq7 that would be the `Paul Revere` rating - one if by land, two if by sea. [shows himself to the door](http://instantrimshot.com/index.php?sound=rimshot&play=true)

Comment: "As far as the regs, it seems that the airplane can simply be considered either land or seaplane class depending on how you are operating it." I would have to see a citation from FAA regs or an FAA legal opinion before I believe you can operate an aircraft certified as a seaplane without a seaplane rating, regardless of the type of floats.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Feel free to request a FSDO interpretation - then you can post it here and it would be a great addition to the site. I would upvote the answer! I've heard there was already a FSDO interpration about this circulated on the Internet, but I haven't been able to find a copy. Rest assured though, it's true!

Comment: @TypeIA Great idea, let us know when you hear from them.

Comment: @JuanJimenez I won't be doing that. Not sure if you misunderstood or are being sarcastic. Either way, no need to reply.

Answer (score 0):

An amphibian may be flown as a land only aircraft without the sea endorsement.  A pilot must not have the intention to land or take-off from water.

Comment: Hi! It would be great if you could give a link to the regulations or some other authoritative source.

Comment: Not authoritative, but from a seaplane association: [FAQ ~ Airman Issues](http://www.seaplanepilotsassociation.org/resources/faq/airman-issues/)